# My only user is not allowed to login into my postgresql server, what can I do?

Tags: postgresql, login

I think that, accidentally, I changed my user to a role with no log in allowed. Now I can't even log in to give log in privileges to the role. Is there something I can do?

I think there was only 1 user and I don't know how to list all my users if I can't log in first.

Thanks

## Addendum

I reinstalled postgres and it seems that no postgres user exists. I installed it via brew:

[image: users and roles according to psql]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main superuser account is set up by initdb when run and will default to the current system user name, not postgres, unless an explicit -u/--username argument is given.  From your above `\du` output it's clear that when you set up the server you did it with your laygr system user as that user is the database server's main superuser account.

Should you mess up your login privileges or forget your password you can get back into the server if you have write access to it's data directory in order to be able to edit pg_hba.conf.  Just change the auth-method on the relevant line to `trust` and reload the server's config via `pg_ctl reload`.  You can then log in, fix your user/password, and then revert the changes you made to pg_hba.conf and reload the config again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the default user `postgres` to login and re-enable your account. Sure, you need to know the `postgres` user's password...

Comment: Maybe it's because I installed postgres via brew, but there is no postgres user...

Comment: As far I know, a postegres user is *always* present on a postgres installation. If you can not find it, try with user `pgsql`

Comment: I already reinstalled postgresql and I can say that when doing `psql \l` and `psql \du` no postgres user or role is shown.

Comment: So, what users are shown on a fresh installation?

Comment: I added a screenshot to the question so that you can see that only one user and role exists. That user/role wouldn't log in since I removed by accident its log in privileges.

Comment: Ok, so you basically disabled/impaired your superuser account. I think re-installation is the only possibility in this case. However, I suggest you to ask on postgresql mailing list for more information.